# Unmute Video onMouseEnter in React Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-video

I am trying to embed a very short video with the HTML  tag into my nextjs page. The video is initially muted and should play sound on hover. I'm more than a bit confused by how weirdly it fails so I'm putting it out there hoping that someone has an answer (or hint for where to look for it).

My code at the moment:

```
    App = () => {
    const [muted, setMuted] = useState(true);
        return (
    <video autoPlay loop onMouseEnter={() => setMuted(false)} muted={muted} >
      <source src='/filename.mp4'>
    </video>
    )}
```

On hover, the muted state is set to false as expected. But then the page behaves very oddly. In Firefox, the video simply stops on hover. On Chrome, it continues to run mutely until I click on the video, then the sound turns on. And Microsoft Edge usually stops (same as firefox) but sometimes at seemingly haphazard intervals it plays sound on click just as Chrome...
Also, inspecting the element in devtools, the attributes don't actually change. Even when the sound is running, it's still set to 'muted' in Chrome, and in Firefox all the attributes equal an empty string (autoplay="").
I have no idea on where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As per the spec, almost all browsers require some user interaction before you can start playing audio. Hover doesn't work for this, Click does though.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I couldn't find a solution within the next framework. I thought it had something to do with ssr. In that case, I'm just going to change my approach. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey in order to play your video, you might get better result using ref with the video. So what you can do is create a ref using useRef hook and give the ref to your video element and on mouse hover use that ref to unmute your video as refs work more better in react and I also used ref and it worked for me. I will show you how I did it

```
    // first create the ref
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const [isMuted, setIsMuted] = useState(false);


    const handleMute = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
    
      setIsMuted((prev) => {
      if (videoRef) {
       videoRef.current!.muted = !prev;
       }

    return !prev;
    });
   };


    <video
      onClick={onVideoClick}
      ref={videoRef}
      src={mobile}
      className="hero-modal-video block h-full w-full cursor-pointer 
      object-cover md:hidden "
      autoPlay

      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovering(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovering(false)}
      poster={videoThumbNail}
      playsInline
      onEnded={handleVideoEnded}

      //   loop
    ></video>
```

Here i am still using the isMuted state to update the ui as well, show the muted and unmuted sound Icon and as well updating the sound of video element as well.

So the ref is setting the muted element of the video to true and false based on the value of the isMuted. That's how i was able to fix it for me.

It's piece of code from my implementation. I am toggling the handleMute function from somewhere else but in your case you can call it using

```
  <video 
   autoPlay 
   loop 
   onMouseEnter={handleMute}
   muted={muted}  // you can remove this attribute
    >
  <source src='/filename.mp4'>
 </video>
```